# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ')' in /home/application/modules/default/controllers/ShoppingCartController.php on line 520

Tags: php, zend-framework

here is the code of my controller class.i read this but i can't find that where is the syntax error.

```
$product_added=false;
//below line is 519
$qr=array("select"=>"exam.*,vendor.vendor as vendor_name","from"=>array("exam","vendor"),
"where"=>array("vendor.id=exam.vendor_id and exam.id=".$post["exam_id"]));
$rd=$this->db->fetchRow($qr);
if(isset($_SESSION) && array_key_exists('cart',$_SESSION) && is_array($_SESSION['cart']) && 
array_key_exists('products',$_SESSION['cart']) )
{   $products=$_SESSION['cart']['products']; }
else
{   $products=$_SESSION['cart']['products']=array(); }
```

Comment: The error is earlier in your document it seems... it compiles without errors with me.

Comment: this code is in switch case if i remove the all code from there program runs successfully,but when i put this code ther the above error comes.

Comment: Put this code in a method/function and then call that method/function in your switch-case, that should narrow down the problem

Comment: Format your code better, no wonder you can't see where a missing bracket is!

Answer (score 1):

Formatted your code better, but looks ok

```
$product_added = false;
$qr = array(
    "select" => "exam.*, vendor.vendor as vendor_name", 
    "from"   => array("exam", "vendor"),
    "where"  => array("vendor.id = exam.vendor_id and exam.id=" . $post["exam_id"])
);
$rd = $this->db->fetchRow($qr);
if(
    isset($_SESSION) && 
    array_key_exists('cart', $_SESSION) && 
    is_array($_SESSION['cart']) && 
    array_key_exists('products', $_SESSION['cart']) 
)
{   
    $products = $_SESSION['cart']['products']; 
}
else
{   
    $products = $_SESSION['cart']['products'] = array(); 
}
```